# laravel Route [resetPassword] not defined

Tags: php, email, laravel

im making a reset password im my application so ive send an email and when i click the link im getting this error

```
ErrorException
Route [resetPassword] not defined. (View:C:\wamp\www\happy_Road\app\views\resetPassword.blade.php)
```

here is the email link

```
http://localhost/happy_Road/public/index.php/resetPassword/3a62d9105691fb0f09084ffdec7e87bcb9e734c0.
```

and the route

```
Route::get('resetPassword/{token}', function($token)
{
   return View::make('resetPassword')->with('token', $token); 
});
```

so what can be the problem !!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the route itself, the problem is that you are trying to link to the route in your blade file (`resetPassword.blade.php`) but you haven't given the route a name.

Take a look at the [Named Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) documentation.

This is what you need to do:

```
Route::get('resetPassword/{token}', ['as' => 'resetPassword', function($token)
{
   return View::make('resetPassword')->with('token', $token); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this could also be done

```
 Route::get('resetPassword/{token}', function($token)
 {
    return View::make('resetPassword')->with('token', $token);

 })->name('resetPassword');
```